# Method add to a linked list doesn't work properly

Tags: java, recursion

I was writing a code to search in a binary tree and add the right node of the current one, everything is perfect because it prints the messages so it's a prove that it works but I don't know why it is not adding the elements to the list despite of the fact it is actually working right.
I'm working it recursively, but I don't find the error. The println's are not very important, just for verification.

```
public List<E> equiposEliminados(E seleccion){
    return equiposEliminados(seleccion, root);
}

private List<E> equiposEliminados(E seleccion, Node<E> n){
    List<E> listaEquipos = new LinkedList<>();
    System.out.println("Nodo actual: "+n.data);
    if(n.right != null && n.data.equals(seleccion)){
        System.out.println("Nodo n (dentro del if): "+n.data);
        System.out.println("Nodo derecho de n (dentro del if): "+n.right.data);
        listaEquipos.add(n.right.data);
    }
    if(n.left != null && n.left.data.equals(seleccion)){
        n = n.left;
        System.out.println("Proximo nodo(nodo izquierdo del actual): "+n.data);
        return equiposEliminados(seleccion, n);
    }
    else if(n.right != null && n.right.data.equals(seleccion)){
        n = n.right;
        System.out.println("Proximo nodo(nodo derecho del actual): "+n.data);
        return equiposEliminados(seleccion, n);
    }
    return listaEquipos;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `List<E> listaEquipos = new LinkedList<>();` is part of the recursive function `equiposEliminados(E seleccion, Node<E> n)` , so it is getting cleared every time. Initilaize the list outside the recursive function.

yes, you can pass listaEquipos as one more parameter to `equiposEliminados(E seleccion, Node<E> n)`.

Then initialize `List<E> listaEquipos = new LinkedList<>()` in

```
public List<E> equiposEliminados(E seleccion){
```

before calling the recursive function in the return statement.

like the following

```
public List<E> equiposEliminados(E seleccion){
    List<E> listaEquipos = new LinkedList<>();
    return equiposEliminados(seleccion, root, listaEquipos);
}


private List<E> equiposEliminados(E seleccion, Node<E> n, List<E> listaEquipos){

    System.out.println("Nodo actual: "+n.data);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I would have to modify the parameters of the private method, right?

Comment: yes, you can pass listaEquipos as one more parameter to equiposEliminados(E seleccion, Node<E> n).

Then initialize List<E> listaEquipos = new LinkedList<>() in 

public List<E> equiposEliminados(E seleccion){

before calling the recursive function in the return statement.